# Center swf on the screen (without html)

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I create a flash animation and I would like to open it as a .exe file. How can I open the exe on the center of the screen? My project is using AS3 but it can be as2 as well. I just need to open this exe on Windows OS.

Comment: If can use AIR , there is option to set window position . I dont think there is any option to do it using only AS3 and flash projector . Maybe You should try to use .NET ? pozdro

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to  do this in pure flash, but there is very easy to do if you use AIR.

Here's an example which centers the window:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities
public function setupWindow():void
{
    var screenX:uint = Capabilities.screenResolutionX
    var screenY:uint = Capabilities.screenResolutionY
    stage.nativeWindow.x = (screenX-stage.nativeWindow.width)/2
    stage.nativeWindow.y = (screenY-stage.nativeWindow.height)/2
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `nativeWindow` property.

Answer (score 0):

a flash window has a property "Startposition"; set it to "CenterScreen"